# How to "unpack" a Monero integrated address using the command line?

Tags: integrated-address

I have 2 questions:

1) how to unpack a Monero integrated address without the wallet RPC (just using common Linux utilities on the command line)? I couldn't find the format of the integrated address (or I didn't search enough)...

2) if I send some XMR to an "unpacked" integrated address, explicitly using the payment_id, it's the same as sending directly to the integrated address, right? I ask because Tux exchange just added XMR with integrated address, but other exchanges don't support withdrawals to an integrated address (Hitbtc for example returns an error).

My idea is to unpack the integrated address and send the old way (using the payment id).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monero addresses are constructed using a particular encoding based on base58, so they aren't unpackable using standard Linux tools.

However, if you're using Monero, then you are probably using simplewallet (now known as monero-wallet-cli), which has a command (`integrated_address`) that will decode an integrated address to its constituent address and payment id. It also has a matching RPC call (`split_integrated_address`) if you want to do this programmatically.

Note that there is a difference between sending with an integrated address and with a plain standard address: integrated addresses use a newer short payment id, which is encrypted on the blockchain. Sending with a plain standard address uses the longer payment id form, which is not encrypted on the blockchain.

On RPC return, short payment ids are represented padded with zeroes to the size of full length payment ids.

Comment: Ok, I managed to right "pad" the payment-id with zeroes. It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

This site helped:

https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html

The relevant code is here:

https://xmr.llcoins.net/js/site.js

on function addrCheck().

Comment: If I add an integrated address in box 8, is one of the other boxes the payment ID?

Comment: Note, you have to have your Javascript console open to see all of the errors, e.g. if you test `40aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa12O` and want to see the error generated by that capital o.