# Is there a guide available for generating and parsing integrated addresses?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, integrated-address

Is there a guide for generating and parsing? I see there is a question regarding "unpacking" them here:
[How to "unpack" a Monero integrated address using the command line?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/how-to-unpack-a-monero-integrated-address-using-the-command-line)

But that doesn't address how to generate them. Do command line or RPC tools like get_bulk_payments work with integrated addresses? I was just looking for a little bit more complete overview of how they work, from generation to receiving, if it's available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an RPC command `make_integrated_address` to make an integrated address with the wallet:

https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc#makeintegratedaddress

Basically, you send the wallet the `payment_id` and it sends back the `integrated_address` for the address associated with the wallet.

There is not a command line function to do this, at least not yet.